# What is time evolution of probability density in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I was surprised to asked this on an exam. The reason being the probability density is described by $\psi^*\psi$ where $\psi$ assumes the form of ~ $cos(kx)exp(-iwt)$

and when we perform  $\psi^*\psi$ the time term cancels out.

So what does it meant by time evolution of probability density when there is no time term?

Comment: The probability density doesn't always have that form for $\psi$.

Comment: The wavefunction you've given is for a plane wave, and since that has the same probability everywhere it's not surprising that it doesn't change. A [wave packet](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qmech/Quantum/node26.html) would have different behaviour.

Comment: @IllegalImmigrant What you got is the density of probability in a standing wave. The amplitude varies in time as you see, but the density of probability doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you were given is a **standing wave**. In such a wave the *density* of energy is distributed in space in a non-even form, as you see in your $cos^2(kx)$, and indeed it doesn't change in time. To the contrary, the amplitude oscillates in time, as you were given. It's a typical interference pattern produced near an impenetrable wall by a monochromatic wave, due to the interference between the incident and reflected wave.

Answer (score 1):

The wave function that you have just described is part of a broader class called stationary states. They are so called since the probability is constant in time. They are eigenfunctions of the energy operator. In your case for instance your wave function is solution of a free particle wave equation.

Comment: Yeah, in general,  one arbitrary wave function is the superposition of eigenfunctions.